# EF6: LINQ with joins and grouping is generating a huge query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've written a LINQ query for entity framework. Results are correct, yet the generated query is huge and I'm a bit worried about performance in the long run.

These are my database tables:

```
Employee     Employee_Position    Position
----------   ------------------   ------------
id           id                   id
firstname    employee_id          name
lastname     position_id          description
gender
birthdate
street
zipcode 
city
phonenr
email
```

The list of objects in which I'm storing the end result of the query look like this:

```
class EmployeesDTO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string phonenr { get; set; }

    public List<string> positionslist { get; set; }
    public string positions
    {
        get
        {
           positionslist.Sort();
           return String.Join(", ", positionslist);
        }
    }
}
```

It's basically a list of employee's with a comma separated list of positions (many-to-many, one employee can have multiple positions and multiple employees can have the same position).

I'm using the following LINQ query with EF6:

```
var q = from m in db.Employees
join ep in db.Employee_Position on m.id equals ep.employee_id
join p in db.Positions on ep.position_id equals p.id
group p.name by new { m.id, m.firstname, m.lastname, m.city, m.phonenr } into g
select new EmployeesDTO
{
    id = g.Key.id,
    firstname = g.Key.firstname,
    lastname = g.Key.lastname,
    city = g.Key.city,
    phonenr = g.Key.phonenr,
    positionslist = g.ToList()
};
return q.ToList();
```

This is generating a large SQL query:

```
SELECT
`Project2`.`id`, 
`Project2`.`firstname`, 
`Project2`.`lastname`, 
`Project2`.`city`, 
`Project2`.`phonenr`, 
`Project2`.`C1`, 
`Project2`.`name`
FROM (SELECT
`Distinct1`.`id`, 
`Distinct1`.`firstname`, 
`Distinct1`.`lastname`, 
`Distinct1`.`city`, 
`Distinct1`.`phonenr`, 
`Join3`.`name`, 
CASE WHEN (`Join3`.`id` IS  NULL) THEN (NULL)  ELSE (1) END AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`firstname`, 
`Extent1`.`lastname`, 
`Extent1`.`city`, 
`Extent1`.`phonenr`, 
FROM `Employees` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `Employee_Position` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`id` = `Extent2`.`employee_id`) AS `Distinct1` LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
`Extent3`.`id`, 
`Extent3`.`firstname`, 
`Extent3`.`lastname`, 
`Extent3`.`gender`, 
`Extent3`.`birthdate`, 
`Extent3`.`street`,
`Extent3`.`zipcode`,  
`Extent3`.`city`, 
`Extent3`.`phonenr`, 
`Extent3`.`email`, 
`Extent4`.`id` AS `ID1`, 
`Extent4`.`employee_id`, 
`Extent4`.`position_id`, 
`Extent5`.`id` AS `ID2`, 
`Extent5`.`name`, 
`Extent5`.`description`, 
FROM `Employees` AS `Extent3` INNER JOIN `Employee_Position` AS `Extent4` ON `Extent3`.`id` = `Extent4`.`employee_id` INNER JOIN `Positions` AS `Extent5` ON `Extent4`.`functie_id` = `Extent5`.`id`) AS `Join3` ON (((((`Distinct1`.`id` = `Join3`.`id`) AND ((`Distinct1`.`firstname` = `Join3`.`firstname`) OR ((`Distinct1`.`firstname` IS  NULL) AND (`Join3`.`firstname` IS  NULL)))) AND ((`Distinct1`.`lastname` = `Join3`.`lastname`) OR ((`Distinct1`.`lastname` IS  NULL) AND (`Join3`.`lastname` IS  NULL)))) AND ((`Distinct1`.`city` = `Join3`.`city`) OR ((`Distinct1`.`city` IS  NULL) AND (`Join3`.`city` IS  NULL)))) AND ((`Distinct1`.`phonenr` = `Join3`.`phonenr`) OR ((`Distinct1`.`phonenr` IS  NULL) AND (`Join3`.`phonenr` IS  NULL)))) AS `Project2`
 ORDER BY 
`Project2`.`id` ASC, 
`Project2`.`firstname` ASC, 
`Project2`.`lastname` ASC, 
`Project2`.`city` ASC, 
`Project2`.`phonenr` ASC, 
`Project2`.`C1` ASC
```

The final result is good (I'm getting a list of EmployeeDBO's with comma separated positions), yet this query looks all over the place. It's even selecting fields which I don't want to (such as employee.gender, employee.birthdate, position.description, etc). I've tried debugging it and the problems seems to be caused by the "group ... by" part.

Is there any way to make this more efficient?

Comment: The statement : positionslist = g.ToList() is causing all the extra fields to get returned.  Just return the value you really need.

Comment: You are correct, leaving this out makes the query look a lot better, but by leaving this out I am not getting a list of the positions for each employee. In the final result I need a comma separated list of positions, is there any way to do this without having to call g.ToList() and returning all those fields?

Comment: Group creates a two dimension object Array(key, List<object>).  So you want positionslist =  g.p.Select(x => x.name).ToList()  If you want csv like data then positionslist =  string.Join(",",g.p.Select(x => x.name).ToList())

Comment: Tried it and what you say is also working, but the SQL query is the same unfortunately. It's still returning fields all over the place.

Comment: Doesn't make a lot of sense.  Removing the positionsList cleans it up, but my new code doesn't.  My code is only referring to one new variable.  Did you try with string.Join?